# Update product's price using the Product object in Prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am looking for a way to update product's price by using the `Product` object. That object however doesn't seem to have any type of function to achieve that.

I come from other e-Commerce platforms where it is possible to call a function like `$product->setPrice($price)` and it updates the product's price.

Is there an equivalent of that in PrestaShop?

If not - I am fine with updating the database directly, but I am worried that updating it directly might miss some crucial hooks that normally trigger when a user modifies the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to instanciate the object, modify the value and save it:

```
$product = new Product(1); // Product ID
$product->price = 10; // Float value
$product->save();
```

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize that the object had a save function! It reminds me of Eloquent in Laravel. Thank you for your help! It solved my problem :).